How do I prevent Firebase access from certain assemblies?
I am using Firebase in Unity.  I am using an MVP design pattern.  The Model, View, and Presenter are each in their own assembly definition.  I only want the model to have access to Firebase.
But it seems as though Firebase is in the standard assembly, and I cannot stop the view from changing things on the cloud.  Is there a way I can stop my View assembly from using anything in the Firebase namespace?
